# How can I print an integer number displaying 4 decimal digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, int

```
print(round(mas[i],4))
```

This only works with float numbers, not integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "4 signs"? Do you mean decimal places or digits?

Comment: An integer is not a float and it won't ever have numbers after the decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format your number using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

```
format(mas[i], '.4f')
```

This formats numbers (including integers) to 4 decimal places. See the [*Format Specification Mini-Language* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Demo:

```
>>> print(format(16, '.4f'))
16.0000
>>> print(format(4.242422, '.4f'))
4.2424
```

If the number is part of a larger string, you can use the format specification in a [`str.format()` format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), using placeholders:

```
'Your frobnar has been opfritzed to {:.4f} hafnavz'.format(mas[i])
```

Comment: Note that this only works up to about 15 or 16 digits before you start getting inaccuracies due to the `float` conversion.

Answer (score 2):

To be complete, you can also use the [printf style formating](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting):

```
>>> '%0.4f' % 4
'4.0000'
>>> '%0.4f' % 4.56789
'4.5679'
>>> '%0.4f' % .1
'0.1000'
```

As stated in the documents, it can be quirky with tuples, but can also be faster.